# How to load IOSurface in OpenGL for Mac OS X Snow Leopard application

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks

Apple added the new IOSurface framework as part of the 10.6 Mac OS X firm update. Since this framework relatively new, I haven't found the much need documentation on how to properly use this.

I was wondering if there anyone on StackOverflow that can assist me with IOSurface usage.

Anyways, this is what I want to do. Right now my application is very simple so that I can become familiar with IOSurfaces. So essentially, I would want to load up an image into an IOSurface texture and display in a custom OpenGLView. That's all I am aiming for at this point.

To make this more simple, I just load one constant color in the IOSurface. My main objective at this point is to create an IOSurface reference and display in a custom OpenGL view.

Please help me with 
-IOSurface declaration statements
-Loading data into the IOSurface
-and the syntax for drawing the IOSurface in OpenGL.

Much appreciated.

p.s.

IOSurface is like a memory manager that passes graphic data between applications or something a long the line of that.

I have tried Google IOSurface. And the most helpful site is

http://cocoadhoc.blogspot.com/2009/09/hidden-gems-of-snow-leopard-iosurface.html

However, when I tried compile the example code, I have a compiler error stating that QTVisualContextRef and other QuickTime variables undeclared. I have the latest version of Quick Time through the automatic update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IOSurface API is quite similar to Core Video's CVPixelBuffer, which is documented, so you could start by looking at the [CVPixelBuffer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreVideoRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001537-CH201-101796) and comparing with IOSurfaceAPI.h.

To bind an OpenGL texture to an IOSurface, see the CGLTexImageIOSurface2D function, which is defined in `<OpenGL/CGLIOSurface.h>`.