# iOS9 framework not found IOSurface

Tags: ios, frameworks, iosurface

When I use `IOSurface.framework`, the problem follows:

```
d: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks' ld: framework not found IOSurface
```

I know IOSurface is a private framework and I just want to install the app into my iPhone, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out this

If it is a "directory not found for option '-L/..." error, that means it's a Library Error, and you should try to:

- Click on your project (targets)
- Click on Build Settings
- Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths

If it is a "directory not found for option '-F/...", that means it's a Framework Error, and you should try to:

- Click on your project (targets)
- Click on Build Settings
- Under Framework Search Paths, delete the paths

Comment: when i delete the paths,problem is "ld: framework not found IOSurface"

Comment: Make sure you have the listed frameworks linked in Build Phase Link Binary with Libraries

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522151/need-help-with-iosurface-opengl-for-max-os-x-snow-leopard-application

Comment: Yes,i have the listed frameworks linked in Build Phase Link Binary with Libraries,but it does not work.The problem is still "ld: framework not found IOSurface"

Comment: the last link is too old to refer,furthermore ,the answer is as if not suitable for  the problem

Comment: Apple closed IOSurface down in iOS 9 ,so we can not use it.Thank you anyway!