# drawing in other processes windows on macosx?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, ipc

Is it possible to draw in other processes windows on MacOSX using Cocoa or other libraries?
If yes, are there any samples? Alternatively a quick summary of what i'd have to do?
*(I need to support at least OSX 10.5)*

Shared memory is of course a possible solution, but i'd prefer direct drawing to avoid synchronization overhead and code duplication (the use-case consists of *one producer* and *n clients*).

Comment: Out of interest can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do with this? Is it some kind of annotation of another application?

Comment: I have one 'master' application and *n* browser plugins that have drawable areas. Ideally i'd like to avoid exchanging image data through an additional buffer in shared memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X: Can one process render to another process's window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583202/mac-os-x-can-one-process-render-to-another-processs-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Mac OS X: Can one process render to another process’s window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583202/mac-os-x-can-one-process-render-to-another-processs-window)
Short answer: If you only need to support >=10.6, you could probably use the IOSurface API.
Details about that in this post: [Need help with IOSurface & OpenGL for max os x snow leopard application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522151/need-help-with-iosurface-opengl-for-max-os-x-snow-leopard-application)

If you can provide more details about what you try to achieve, there might be some other solutions. (e.g. Compositing the things you intend to render onto an image from [CGWindowListCreateImage](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008073-CH2-SW1))

**Edit:**
To me it seems that the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to use some sort of shared memory.
You could map the data to visualize into memory with [mmap](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) and share the drawing code between your applications.

**Edit2:**
I just saw that you want to avoid shared memory. But why?

Comment: Thanks for that. What i get out of it though is *it might work with NSWindowSharingReadWrite but i don't know how* - maybe someone figured it out in the mean-time?

Comment: I recently also investigated the sharing state (but for reading, not for writing) - I coulnd't find anything useful.
If you are more successful, please post your results back here.

Comment: Regarding shared memory, mainly 2 reasons: a) i don't want the overhead of synchronisation etc. b) i want to keep the drawing code out of the clients if possible. What if i'd e.g. decode directly in or into a video buffer?

Comment: Well, i wasn't more successful... so i'm accepting your answer.