# One App Drawing on Another's NSView

Tags: cocoa, ipc, nsview

This will probably come across as a naive question, but is there anyway possible for one application to have access to an `NSView` object belonging to another application and draw on it (via IPC or otherwise)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X: Can one process render to another process's window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583202/mac-os-x-can-one-process-render-to-another-processs-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's exactly what the [`IOSurface` framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/IOSurfaceAPI_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) is for. A good example of its use is Safari in Lion, which has a rendering process that is separate to the HTML parsing process.

There's a good article about it [here](http://cocoadhoc.blogspot.com/2009/09/hidden-gems-of-snow-leopard-iosurface.html).

Note that if your app is in a Sandbox that you can't use IPC to communicate with an app outside your app's sandbox, but you can communicate with helper tools inside the sandbox.

Comment: Not sure yet whether or not IOSurface will work for me.  I'm using a third party library to which I hand an NSView, and it does all the rendering of video captured from a camera for me.  I just want it be able to render to an NSView in another process.  So I will somehow need to extract the graphic data from one NSView and send it to the other process's NSView.